# Partitioned data format in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, pyspark

While writing data to S3 bucket in partitioned format, folders get created as `year=2020/Month=10`.

I want folder named as `year2020/Month10`

Comment: Why do you want the folder to be names as such? spark doesn't provide options to rename partitioned folders. This is expected and desired behavior.

Comment: We receive raw partitioned files in same format(year2020/month10) ,so we want to maintain the same structure across each bucket

Comment: I can't find anything anywhere which says about custom partition in spark. Please self-answer this question if you find something. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading as **`static partitions`** instead of **`dynamic partitions`** then you can achieve the expected output.

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([(1,'a','2020','10'),(2,'b','2020','10')],['id','name','year','month'])

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.show()
#+---+----+----+-----+
#| id|name|year|month|
#+---+----+----+-----+
#|  1|   a|2020|   10|
#|  2|   b|2020|   10|
#+---+----+----+-----+

#get year,hour value and assign to variable
year=df.select("year").collect()[0][0]
month=df.select("month").collect()[0][0]

#we are going to create directories 
df.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save(f"year{year}/month{month}")
#year2020/month10/parquet files
```